# I have a error with codeigniter in local host with xamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, codeigniter-3

I Have a project in codeigniter and I'm using xampp, i have a button but when I redirect to other view i got an error.

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested
>   object.

It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.4

> My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> My config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sigere/';


$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and my link that doesnt work

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/views/index.php" </a>
```

Comment: Yes you cannot directly access a view like that and it makes no sense to do so. You make links to controllers/methods which call up the appropriate view(s). I think you need to revisit the codeigniter user guide and read up on how it works.

Comment: But When o try to access to other controller different to the default i have a error -- You dont hace permission to acces the request object ---

Comment: When I acces via Ajax i get this error to

Comment: Can you provide some code to show this? Tis a bit hard to see what you are doing without it.

Comment: can you please add your routes in your question for better understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stated issue I am not sure just how much you know about using Codeigniter.

You cannot access anything under the application folder directly from the URL with the exception of controller/method links *as a general rule*.

As an example to have a link to display a page, your link might be

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home Page</a>
```

This is a link to your default controllers index method. So it's something like a "Home Page".

Lets say your default controller is called **Home_controller** as set in your **application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home_controller';
```

**The view**

Your "index.php" view, I'll rename it to **home_view.php**

**Your application/controllers/Home_controller.php**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('home_view'); // show view called index (bad name)
    }
}
```

Without going into some full blown tutorial, this is using CI in it's simplest form just to give a quick demonstration of how to access a view.